# Parallel execution of a snakemake rule with same input and a range of values for a single parameter

Tags: snakemake

I am transitioning a bash script to snakemake and I would like to parallelize a step I was previously handling with a for loop. The issue I am running into is that instead of running parallel processes, snakemake ends up trying to run one process with all parameters and fails.

My original bash script runs a program multiple times for a range of values of the parameter `K`.

```
for num in {1..3}
do
  structure.py -K $num --input=fileprefix --output=fileprefix
done
```

There are multiple input files that start with `fileprefix`. And there are two main outputs per run, e.g. for K=1 they are `fileprefix.1.meanP`, `fileprefix.1.meanQ`. My config and snakemake files are as follows.

Config:

```
cat config.yaml

infile: fileprefix
K:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
```

Snakemake:

```
configfile: 'config.yaml'

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}.{K}.{ext}",
            sample = config['infile'],
            K = config['K'],
            ext = ['meanQ', 'meanP'])

rule structure:
    output:
        "output/{sample}.{K}.meanQ",
        "output/{sample}.{K}.meanP"
    params:
        prefix = config['infile'],
        K = config['K']
    threads: 3
    shell:
        """
        structure.py -K {params.K} \
        --input=output/{params.prefix} \
        --output=output/{params.prefix}
        """
```

This was executed with `snakemake --cores 3`. The problem persists when I only use one thread.

I expected the outputs described above for each value of K, but the run fails with this error:

```
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 84 of Snakefile:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  structure.py -K 1 2 3 --input=output/fileprefix \
--output=output/fileprefix ' returned non-zero exit status 2.
  File "Snakefile", line 84, in __rule_Structure
  File "snake/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
```

When I set K to a single value such as `K = ['1']`, everything works. So the problem seems to be that `{params.K}` is being expanded to all values of K when the shell command is executed. I started teaching myself snakemake today, and it works really well, but I'm hitting a brick wall with this.

Comment: Doesn't affect my question, but in the `params` it should read `prefix = config['infile']`and not  `prefix = config['invcf']`.

Comment: Your question can be edited for corrections (as many times as you want, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the argument for `-K` from the wildcards, not from the config file. The config file will simply return your list of possible values, it is a plain python dictionary.

```
configfile: 'config.yaml'

rule all:
    input:
        expand("output/{sample}.{K}.{ext}",
               sample = config['infile'],
               K = config['K'],
               ext = ['meanQ', 'meanP'])

rule structure:
    output:
        "output/{sample}.{K}.meanQ",
        "output/{sample}.{K}.meanP"
    params:
        prefix = config['invcf'],
        K = config['K']
    threads: 3
    shell:
        "structure.py -K {wildcards.K} "
        "--input=output/{params.prefix} "
        "--output=output/{params.prefix}"
```

Note that there are more things to improve here. For example, the rule `structure` does not define any input file, although it uses one.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option now for parameter space exploration
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#parameter-space-exploration